# How to create a custom Lycanthrope in HeroForge Anew?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tools, character-templates, lycanthropy

One of my players will probably end up becoming a Wereshark next session. To create our character sheets, we use [HeroForge Anew](https://sites.google.com/site/heroforgeanew/). However, this program only recognises the Lycanthropes from the monster-manual. I already tried making a custom template for it, but I didn't manage to add any Animal Hit-dice.

Is there any way to either add "Shark" to the list of base animals for the already existing Lycanthrope Template, add custom animals to that same list of base animals, or add Animal HD to a human character in HeroForge? Alternatively, is there another program out there than can get me these results?

By the time the player in question gets this template, he is a 2nd level Human Barbarian.

Comment: What game are you talking about? D&D? If so, which edition?

Comment: I don't know enough about how to add custom content to HeroForge to provide a proper answer, but something that might help:  The HeroForge project is currently maintained by Heliomance out of the GitP forums; she's very likely to be able to provide you with this sort of help.  You can PM her there from her user profile:  http://www.giantitp.com/forums/member.php?21718-Heliomance

Comment: I'm talking about D&D 3.5
And thanks, I'll check her out.

Comment: If you find a solution, please answer your question for future users.